# Neural Prophet Not Predicting At All?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, facebook-prophet

I am trying to predict the number of customers entering a certain beach. As such, the numbers in the data tend to fluctuate, and wish to use Neural Prophet in order to predict future guests. However, with the current setup that I have for my Neural Prophet Model, the model is simply not predicting past the final date in the original data, even though for other parameters it does predict, just not accurately.

Here is what the predictions look like (Dashed line) vs. Original (Solid Line):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qP8SE.png)

I specifically asked to forecast the next 100 days, but that's not showing at all.
Here is my set-up for the model:

```
 model = NeuralProphet(
        #growth="off",  # Determine trend types: 'linear', 'discontinuous', 'off'
        # changepoints=None, # list of dates that may include change points (None -> automatic )
        n_changepoints=0,
        # changepoints_range=0,
        # trend_reg=0,
        # trend_reg_threshold=False,
        # # seasonality_reg=1,
        # # d_hidden = 0,
        n_lags=10,
        # # num_hidden_layers=0,     # Dimension of hidden layers of AR-Net
        # # ar_reg=None,  # Sparcity in the AR coefficients
        learning_rate=0.01,
        epochs=100,
        normalize="auto",  # Type of normalization ('minmax', 'standardize', 'soft', 'off')
        impute_missing=True,        
        yearly_seasonality=True,
        weekly_seasonality=False,
        daily_seasonality= False,
        seasonality_mode="multiplicative",
        loss_func="MSE",
    )

    # Fit the model to the training data
    model.fit(data,freq="D")  
    future = model.make_future_dataframe(data, periods=1000,n_historic_predictions=len(data))
    forecast = model.predict(future)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have basically the same problem, it's due to the new update 0.6.2, 0.5.1 worked fine, but basically the new version seems a bit broken. I have understood that the problem is because of the parameter n_lags, it basically tries to forecast "backwards".

You can check this iusse:
https://github.com/AlbertoAlmuinha/neuralprophet/issues/8

Basically you have to add rows for the number of n_lags at the dataframe, or alternatively going back to 0.5.1.

Comment: I tried this out, but it did not work.

Comment: Yeah it seems it doesn't solve the iusse, also previous versions have the same problem when using n_lags parameter.

Comment: Ok maybe I find out the problem, the real problem is as you use the future = model.make_future_dataframe(data, periods=1000,n_historic_predictions=len(data))

If you check future dataframe when you are using the parameter n_lags it doesn't work as it should, it doesn't generate the future, so maybe if you can avoid using the method make_future_dataframe to generate the future dataframe, maybe we can work it around, I am currently testing this.

Comment: for reference, I used this article when initially coding. They utilize the same methodology as I did:
https://github.com/e-alizadeh/data-science-blog/blob/master/notebooks/NeuralProphet/neural_prophet.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

So I have understood the problem: when you use `n_lags`, `n_forecast` is set as default to 1, so `model.predict(future)` doesn't predict 100 days off.

Note:
The final values of the dataframe "forecast" will be stored on the diagonal of the dataframe, if you want all the values in a single column `yhat1` I made this function:

```
def exctract_yhat(forecasts, size):
  columns = forecasts.columns[3:]
  newframe = forecasts[['ds', 'yhat1']].iloc[-size:].copy()
  for col in columns:
      if 'yhat' in col:
         newframe['yhat1'] = newframe['yhat1'].fillna(forecasts[col])
  return newframe
```

#size is = n_forecasts parameters

Answer (score 0):

The problem is by default, when you use `make_future_dataframe` using model object, the model will only predict `n_forecasts` ahead. In this case, the default value for `n_forecasts` is 1. Hence, you will only see 1 step future prediction. If you want the model to predict 7 days ahead, you have to train the model with `n_forecasts=7`.

If you want to know your model's hyperparam values, use `model.model.n_forecasts` to check the value.